# fillSelectors and variables on casperJS

Tags: variables, fill, casperjs

I have a simple problem, but i don't know the solution.

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.fillSelectors(argFormSelector,{
        argLoginSelector : argLogin,
        argPwdSelector : argPwd
    },true);
});
```

But in debug_mode i do not see anything... It looks like:

```
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 http://urlwebsite/ (HTTP 200) 
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector:
'form[action^="/remote.php?act=formTargetGag"]' 
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 1950ms.
```

But if I try to do the same without variables, everything is ok:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.fillSelectors(argFormSelector,{
'input[id="login_email"]': argLogin,
'input[id="login_password"]':argPwd
},true);
});
```

---Log---

```
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[action^="/remote.php?act=formTargetGag"]' 
[debug] [remote] Set "email" field value to spider.batman.93@mail.ru 
[debug] [remote] Set "password" field value to ********* [info] [remote] submitting form to /remote.php?act=formTargetGag, HTTP POST
```

So my question is: why couldn't I use variables in fillSelectors? I mean in left part, because in right part all is ok, that you can see.

I put data in variables like this:

```
var a = { argLoginSelectors: argLogin, argPwdSelectors: argPwd}
for(i in a)
 console.log(i+':'+a[i]);
this.fillSelectors(argFormSelector,a,true);
```

But nothing happened. I have the same in log:

```
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 http://urlwebsite/ (HTTP 200) 
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector:
'form[action^="/remote.php?act=formTargetGag"]' 
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 1950ms.
```

Please help me:) What i'm doing wrong?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What do you have in argLoginSelectors and argPwdSelectors ?